# Is every application using anything dependent on VC++9 runtime required to have a manifest embedded?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, visual-c++, runtime

I don't get what [this article on R6034](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235560.aspx) says. Looks like it states that every application dependent on VC++9 runtime must have a manifest.

Now we have a DLL that we ship to customers, that depends on VC++9 runtime and has a manifest embedded. Does every application using our DLL also need to have a manifest embedded?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, your customers do not need manifests. The loader deals with manifests for every image it loads... so if your DLL has a manifest it will be parsed/applied properly, regardless of how your DLL is loaded.